# Setting Brave / Chrome Workspaces Permission Issue

Tags: permissions, google-chrome, workspaces, ownership, brave

I work on local websites and want to add workspaces in Brave Dev Tools. When I try to add the folders, I get the error

`Could not read the contents of var. Error opening directory '/var': Permission denied`

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and installed Brave through Ubuntu Software.

The folder var is owned by `root:root` and has these permissions: `drwxr-xr-x`

How can I get Brave workspaces to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meanwhile I figured this out by myself.

The issue was that I installed Brave as a snap. I did not know about this before, but snaps generally run in a sandbox to enhance their security for end users:

https://ubuntu.com/blog/a-guide-to-snap-permissions-and-interfaces

Part of that security is that they can just access your home folder, nothing like /var/www or similar.

Solution: Remove snap of Brave and install through apt-get:

https://brave.com/linux/